# Why does the navigator object seem to report incorrect information?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

A wild Netscape has appeared! ... but seriously, does anyone know why the "navigator" JS object seems to be blatantly incorrect? It also seems to think I'm on a Mac with an Intel processor, when I definitely have an M1

[image]

Comment: The version string has stuff in it for historical reasons; it's basically meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving away from a browser-dependent solution due to the historical context provided by this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-user-agent-that-crazy-string-underpinning-a-bunch-of-analytics-86507ef632f0

In essence, user-agent was a loosely-defined spec in the early days of the web, and the current use-case for UA of determining the browser a user is accessing your site from is not appropriate as a result.